# How do I add onclick="select_all(this)" dynamically with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I found this awesome possum that makes it possible to `select_all` the text in a span tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function select_all(el) {
        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
            var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            textRange.moveToElementText(el);
            textRange.select();
        }
    }
</script>


<span class="select-all" onclick="select_all(this)">This text becomes selectable</span>
```

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j26design/09wb3qv5/3/)

My question is, how might I be able to dynamically add the inline javascript to all span tags with the `select-all` class? I'm still a newbie with javascript and so I couldn't seem to find anything that mentioned how to do this (that or it confused me).

Comment: why do you want to do that... use jQuery based event handlers instead of online one

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yvy2vjh4/1/

Comment: Oh wow that's way better haha thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you create a `click` event handler for all the existent elements having `select-all` `class`:

```
$(".select-all").click(function() {
    //do something
});
```

This is how you define an event handler for all the existent `span`s having `select-all` `class`:

```
$("span.select-all").click(function() {
    //do something
});
```

This is how you define an event handler for all the existent and future elements having `select-all` `class`:

```
$("body").on("click", ".select-all", function(e) {
    //do something
});
```

This is how you define an event handler for all the existent and future `span`s having `select-all` `class`:

```
$("body").on("click", "span.select-all", function(e) {
    //do something
});
```

If you want a specific event handler for all existent and future `span`s having `select-all` `class` inside a container, having a `selector`, then this is how you do it:

```
$(selector).on("click", "span.select-all", function(e) {
    //do something
});
```

Note, that `selector` is `"body"` in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.select-all').click(function (el) {
        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
            var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            textRange.moveToElementText(el);
            textRange.select();
        }
    });
});
```

Happy Coding.